# Access home network from an external IP address

Tags: networking, router, proxy, port-forwarding

I'm tapping into the PhilipsHue API to turn on/off lights. However, I can only do this on my home's internal network and so I want to be able to access it from the outside so here is what I tried after doing some research on how to do it.

1. My node app that hosts this api is running on `localhost:80` on my mac so it's pretty much my local, internal server. This mac has an internal IP of `192.168.1.220`.
2. I logged into my router settings and forwarded port `6000` to my Mac.

[image]

3. So then, I tried accessing my app through `<Gateway IPv4 Address>:6000` which from what I understand is the external IP address of my router. I was expecting it to act similar to an nginx proxy pass where requests coming in on `<Gateway IPv4 Address>:6000` would get routed to `192.168.1.220:80` (my mac's internal IP address) but no luck. Postman says "could not get any response".

Comment: Most likely, you will need to forward port 80 on your router. Most residential routers forward ports 1:1 by default. You should double-check your router's WAN address from inside the router to make sure that you are receiving a public address on your router. Many ISPs are using CGN, and this will break your port forwarding, and almost all residential ISPs have a clause in their agreements which disallows you from running a server on you network to the Internet, and if they break your server with CGN, they don't really care.

Comment: What do you mean when you say `Gateway IPv4 Address`? Is it in the `192.xxx`-range? Then it is your routers internal IP but you have to use its WAN-IP.

Comment: Are you sure that your ISP allows access through port 6000?

Comment: Question: you wriite that you can access the API via `localhost:80` on your mac.  Can you also access it from `192.168.1.220:80`?

Answer (score 1):

There could many reasons for this occur. 
Chances are that your connection is DHCP and it is possible you tried connecting after the lease renewed. You should contact your ISP and check if they will allow you a static address, if not, invest in a modem or router that has VPN capability.

Second, you did not give details on if your firewall is enabled on the mac. If so, make an exception for your connection.

Third, i'm not sure how you have your infrastructure. Do you have a modem/router combo or do you have a modem that forwards traffic to a modem. If you have two pieces of equipment, one of those devices may be blocking the traffic. Check your modem and router's log and see if you can see the connection.

Fourth, even though you forwarded port 6000, you may still need to forward 80 as that is the port you are connecting through. Port 6000 is simple the port on the server which you need to go to. This is most likely what is wrong, but put it last so you can verify other steps first :D

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @RonMaupin .

This configuration is called PAT. It allows us map a port of external IP address to a port of internal IP address. Normally, we need 4 parameter to configure it.

1. external IP address (By default, it's the WAN ip address of your
   router)
2. external port (In your case, it's 6000)
3. internal IP address (In your case, it's 192.168.1.220)
4. internal port (It should be 80 and it's missing in your screenshot, 
   so I would suspect if your router supports redirecting the external request to a different port)